# Two continuous functions from $X$ to $S^n$ satisfying $|f(x) - g(x)|<2, \forall x$, are homotopic to each other.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am trying to solve a problem, as mentioned in the title:

> Given two continuous functions $f,g : X \to S^n $ such that $|f(x) - g(x)|<2$,    $\forall x $, then $f$ is homotopic to $g$, i.e. $ f \sim g $.

What I am trying to solve this by using that for two continuous functions $ f,g : X \to S^n $ such that $f(x) \neq -g(x),\, \forall x $, then $ f \sim g $. And for that, I need to conclude $f(x) \neq -g(x)$ from $|f(x) - g(x)|<2$. But I have not succeeded yet....

If anyone has some other approach or solution, please provide... 
Thanks

Comment: What is the diameter of the sphere?

Comment: The condition implies that $f(x)\neq -g(x)$ for all $x$ (or else?). So?

Comment: Suppose $f(x) = g(x)$ for some $x$. Then $|f(x)-g(x)| = 2|g(x)| = 2$ (assuming the sphere is radius 1)

Comment: Ivo Terek, for that case, I have a continuous mapping that make f and g homotopic...

Comment: Connor Malin: The maximum distance between any two points on sphere..... Or the straight line between 2 distinct points passing through the origin...

Comment: George Dewhirst: I need to conclude  f(x) not eq to -g(x)... If i take, it gives me the interval for g(x) which satisfies both...

Comment: $2|g(x)| = 2$ is a contradiction hence $f(x) \neq -g(x)$ for any $x$. Many apologies my original comment should read "suppose $f(x) = -g(x)$ for some $x$"

Answer (score 2):

If $S^n$ denotes the unit sphere then notice that $|v - (-v)| = |2 v| = 2$ for every $v\in S^n$. Therefore if the condition "$\forall x\in X\ |f(x) -g(x)| <2 $" holds then in particular $\forall x\in X\ g(x) \neq -f(x)$.